# Soundness and consistency in type theory

Tags: logic, category-theory, first-order-logic, type-theory

On page 9 of the paper [*Simplicial Model of Univ. Foundations*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.2851.pdf), we have the following brief discussion of consistency:

[image]

It seems that, assuming soundness, in type theory we have that any theory with a model is consistent. But then it must be the case that there is never such a section of $p_{0_1}$, correct? If this is correct, then how do we verify that such a section is never possible? If not, then how do we prove that having a model implies consistency (presumably in a way similar to the classical version, which follows easily from soundness)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> any theory with a model is consistent.

This is not the case. For instance, every algebraic theory has an initial and a terminal model, but neither of these have a bearing on consistency.

The initial model is the syntax of a theory, and consistency is a statement about definability in the syntax. So the initial model is just part of the setup. The terminal model is a model where all underlying sets are given as the singleton set; e.g. the terminal category is the singleton category. Terminal models don't imply anything about the syntax; they're trivial.

There can be other models, neither terminal nor initial, which interpret the empty type as a nonempty set, and thus don't imply syntactic consistency. Consistency only follows from a model which interprets the empty type with an empty set or an analogous "empty" structure.

Comment: I'm actually confused again. When it says that Theorem 3.4.3 can be read as proving consistency, what is the justification for this? It seems, based on your explanation, that the $\mathbf{sSet}$ model they construct interprets the empty type as an empty structure.  But how do we know this is the case?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Definition 1.4.11 introduces the empty type. Theorem 2.3.4 interprets it, they don't give any detail other than "straightforward". The empty type should be essentially the empty Kan complex in the model.

Comment: Thank you, in conclusion, would you say that the description of the relation between soundness and consistency found at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/type+theory#semantics_of_typetheoretical_foundations is simply incorrect?

Comment: The "Semantics of type-theoretical foundations" section is mostly from a classical model-theoretic perspective, which is rarely used in the practice of semantics of type theory. There, the notion of model is greatly restricted, the last paragraph of "Term model" mentions the notion of model which is actually used in the simplicial model paper.